# Wrong Number of arguments, or invalid property assignment: 'instr' line 5

Tags: vbscript

Hey I wanted to take the loop below and also make it skip admin shares if the share starts with "_*o _*"

my loop is:

```
'Compares The UnApproved Shares to the Current Shares
    For Each objItem In colItems
        Dim StrNonUnapprovedShares, Item
        StrCurrentShares = objItem.name
    if instr(AdminShares,lcase(objitem.name)) > 0 or mid(objitem.name,2,1) = "$" or left(lcase(objitem.name),10) = "pkgsvrhost" or instr("_o_") > 0 then
        'Skipping known admin share
    Else
            For each Item in arrUnApprovedLines
            If Lcase(Item) = Lcase(strCurrentShares) Then
                StrNonUnapprovedShares = (StrNonUnapprovedShares & strCurrentShares & vbCrLf)
            End If

        Next
    End If
Next
```

I inserted an "or instr("_*O _*")" after the "pkgsvrhost" on the 5th line, but it errored with the error --type mismatch" '[string: "_*O _*"]--

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Or Instr(objitem.name, "_O_") > 0
```

Comment: Beware that this will evaluate to `True` if the name has `_O_` *anywhere* in it, though. To check if the name *starts* with `_O_` use the condition `Left(objitem.Name, 3) = "_O_"`.